# Custom Post Type & Page Template

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I have a custom post type :

```
   add_action('init', 'dossierinfo_register');    


function dossierinfo_register() {
    register_post_type( 'dossier' , array(
        'label' => __('Dossiers'),
        'singular_label' => __('Dossier'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'menu_position' => 3,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes')
       ));    
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

and a page template named page-dossier.php with

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Dossiers
*/?>
```

But i can't use it ! It's not working.
The template working like a charm in normal pages but not in custom post type.

Obviously i flushed my rewrite rules ans permalink in admin area…

I don't know what to do !
Any ideas ?

'scuse my english i'm french

Thank !

EDIT: Is it possible that i'm working on a subdomain ?

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT use flush_rewrite_rules when you register your custom post type. 
Doing so means you will flush permalinks on every page load. 
Instead you should use the [register_activation_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook).

Re the template issue: Try renaming the template to single-dossier.php

And try changing your  register_post_type array to this:

```
register_post_type( 'dossier' , array(
    'label' => __('Dossiers'),
    'singular_label' => __('Dossier'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'dossier' ),
    'capability_type' => array('dossier', 'dossiers'),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'menu_position' => 3,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes')
   ));
```

Comment: Ok for the flush-rewrite, i deleted it. But i also tried renaming to single-dossier and it didn't work too.

Comment: See edit above re register post type

Comment: Ok, if i try changing by this, i don't see "Dossier" in my admin panel :S